# Could someone explain the issue with this function chain? Not getting intended functionality

Tags: javascript, method-chaining

I am trying to understand JS and jQuery and have some code to append an element to the DOM. I try and create a text node and append it to the element node and then append that to the first div tag, all in one statement. I understand this is probably bad practice but I just wanted to see if it were possible. It seems like it should work because createElement() returns the new element object and I call the appendChild() on that object which appends the returned object from createTextNode(). Yet what actually occurs is the text node gets appended, but not as a div. It seems it bypasses the createElement function for some reason. Could someone explain why please? I even put it in brackets to make sure it executes first to no avail.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  'use strict';
  window.onload = () => {
    let dir = console.dir;
    let log = console.log;
    $('h1').hide();
    $('body').click(() => $('h1').show('slow', () => log('called')));
  };

  function appendDiv() {
    document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0]
      .appendChild((document.createElement('div'))
        .appendChild(document.createTextNode('AppendedDiv')));
  }
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="heading1" onclick="appendDiv();">JavaScript and jQuery Practice</h1>
  <p>Practice using JavaScript and jQuery here!</p>
  <div>DIV</div>
  <div>DIV</div>
  <div>DIV</div>
  <div>DIV</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`appendChild` returns the appended child--so calling `elem.appendChild(div.appendChild(text))` would actually append `text` to `elem` and not a `div` with child `text` like you intended. You should just separate it out:

```
function appendDiv() {
  const child = document.createElement('div');
  child.appendChild(document.createTextNode('AppendedDiv'));

  document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0]
    .appendChild(child);
}
```

Comment: I sort of get where you are coming from. But don't chained functions evaluate from left to right? First the div object is obtained, then I call appendChild to set and return the newly created div element, then I call the appendChild on the returned div child to append the text?

Comment: If you want that, you could do what others suggested which is `elem.appendChild(div).appendChild(text)`. Because of the way you wrapped it, it was instead `elem.appendChild(div.appendChild(text))`. The parenthesis here are different, and because `div.appendChild(text)` will return `text`, it's like doing `elem.appendChild(text)`.

Comment: Oh, I see now. Yeah, I thought I was using the the proper method all along, I did not realise I had misplaced brackets! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra () in the first append call

Answer (score 1):

Your parentheses are mismatched. Instead of appending the `div` and then appending the `AppendedDiv` text to it, you're appending the `AppendedDiv` text to the original div. See comment in this code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  'use strict';
  window.onload = () => {
    let dir = console.dir;
    let log = console.log;
    $('h1').hide();
    $('body').click(() => $('h1').show('slow', () => log('called')));
  };

  function appendDiv() {
    document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0]
      .appendChild(document.createElement('div')) // <-- Match parentheses like this
        .appendChild(document.createTextNode('AppendedDiv')); // <- Match
  }
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="heading1" onclick="appendDiv();">JavaScript and jQuery Practice</h1>
  <p>Practice using JavaScript and jQuery here!</p>
  <div>DIV</div>
  <div>DIV</div>
  <div>DIV</div>
  <div>DIV</div>
```

This is a great reason to break these things down into multiple steps instead of doing it all in one go, which you are correct in thinking is "probably bad practice"! It's easy for subtle bugs like this to creep in.

Best practice would be to break it up into a few steps, something like this:

```
const wrapper = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
const childDiv = document.createElement('div');
wrapper.appendChild(childDiv);
childDiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode('AppendedDiv'));
```

So much more readable!

Comment: Thanks for the tip!